# LWJGL error "function is not supported" for GL11.glMatrixMode()

Tags: java, lwjgl

I will post the code first then the problem below:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;

import ref.Reference;
import ref.Settings;

public class Main implements Runnable {

private static int width;
private static int height;

private long lastframe;
private int fps;
private long lastfps;

private float rotation = 0;
private float x = 400;
private float y = 300;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;
private static Properties settings = new Properties();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main game = new Main();
    Settings.load();
    settings = Settings.getSettings();  
    game.initDisplay(); 
    game.initGL();  
    game.start();
}

public void run() { 
    System.out.println("Start");    
    getDelta();
    lastfps = getTime();    
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {           
        if (running) {
            int delta = getDelta();             
            tick(delta);                
            Display.sync(60);
        }           
        render();           
        updateFPS();            
        Display.update();
    }   
    if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        stop();
        cleanup();
    }
}

private void updateFPS() {
    if (getTime() - lastfps > 1000) {
        System.out.println("FPS: " + fps);
        fps = 0;
        lastfps += 1000;
    }
    fps++;
}

private void tick(int delta) {
    System.out.println("Tick"); 
    rotation += 0.15f * delta;  
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)) x -= 0.35f * delta;
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)) x += 0.35f * delta;
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) y -= 0.35f * delta;
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) y += 0.35f * delta;
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    if (x > 800) x = 800;
    if (y < 0) y = 0;
    if (y > 600) y = 600;       
}

private void render() {
    System.out.println("Render");
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    GL11.glRotatef(rotation, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x - 50, y - 50);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + 50, y - 50);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + 50, y + 50);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x - 50, y + 50);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

private void cleanup() {
    Mouse.destroy();
    Keyboard.destroy();
    Display.destroy();
}

public void initGL() {  
    System.out.println("initGL");
    GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

public void initDisplay() {
    System.out.println("initDisplay");

    try {
        width = Integer.parseInt(settings.getProperty("width"));
        height = Integer.parseInt(settings.getProperty("height"));      
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.setTitle(Reference.WINDOWTITLE);
        Display.create();
        Keyboard.create();
        Mouse.create();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void start() {
    if (running) return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}

public void stop() {
    if (!running) return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

private long getTime() {
    return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
}

public int getDelta() {
    long time = getTime();
    int delta = (int) (time - lastframe);
    lastframe = time;   
    return delta;
}

}
```

Now when starting it I get thie error:

```
initDisplay
initGL
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.java:2075)
    at Main.initGL(Main.java:127)
    at Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

This is basically the code from the LWJGL Wiki, I was just copying it to see if the thread works and ran into this. It's a new thing to me so can anybody maybe help and tell me what is incorrect? Because I don't get it.

Line 127 is the first line of initGL() (I deleted empty lines for this so it's not 127 anymore, but that was the line where the error happened):

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
```

Works fine without the thread btw

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL calls (from one GL context) can only run on one thread. Your code runs OpenGL code in the same GL context over two different threads. On the default thread you run `game.initDisplay()` and `game.initGL()`, and on your own new thread you run the remaining OpenGL code. You either need to make sure that all OpenGL calls are made from one thread, or look into context sharing. I'd go for a single thread until that proves to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error basically means that for this version of OpenGL, the function is not supported. You are either using an old version of OpenGL or a newer version that does not support it. To set the version, instead of Display.create(), do Display.create(new PixelFormat(), new ContextAttributes(3, 0)), which will set your OpenGL version to 3.0, a version that supports glMatrixMode.